# How to read in 8 bytes of data from a DataInputStream and interpreted it as double in Vala

Tags: vala

I looking for the equivalent of 
java.io.DataInputStream.readDouble() for Vala.
Is it even possible?
Currently I have :

```
    public double data;

    public override void load (DataInputStream dis) throws IOError {
        data = dis.read_int64 ();
    }
```

But it just converting a int64 to a double which is not what I want.
I've tried all sort of casting and de-referencing, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
int main()
{
    int64 foo = 0; // Whatever value you have
    double data = *(double*)(&foo); // This is where the "magic" happens
    stdout.printf("%f", data);
    return 0;
}
```

Mind you, you may have to set the correct [byte order](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gio-2.0/GLib.DataInputStream.set_byte_order) for the conversion to succeed.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I missed out on the &foo as I was trying to do everything on a single line.